# How to use bitwise operators in HQL?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

In HQL, how can I use bitwise operators? I want the resulting SQL query to look something like

```
SELECT RoleId, RoleName, RolePerms WHERE (RolePerms & @Parameter) = @Parameter
```

However, writing this HQL

```
select from Role where (RolePerms & :param) = :param
```

gives me this error: *NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this. Writing the HQL this way works:

```
select r from Role r where (r.Permissions & :param) > 0
```

Comment: You might want to worry about the > operator since if you set your sign bit, the value might be negative. Unless it's an unsigned type... but I'd just use <> if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

From section 13.8 of the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html), HQL does not support these bitwise operators. You'd have to revert to native SQL (see section 15).

Comment: That's what I thought too until I found a test (http://bit.ly/1Wjk1) while going through NHibernate's source. According to the test, it seems to be possible.

Comment: In that case it looks like this might be something that has been fixed in 2.1, or will be fixed in a subsequent release. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to the NHibernate Jira it looks like this should be working as of 2.1.0Beta2, https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1192.