# & and | operators in NHibernate criteria

Tags: nhibernate

I need to write with NHibernate criteria something like:

```
SELECT something FROM sometable
WHERE (something & 1) = 1
```

where "something" is int.

I don't know how to write the WHERE part with criteria:

```
ICriteria _Criteria = CreateCriteria();
_Criteria.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("something", ???);
```

It is possible in NHibernate? If not, exist any alternative solution if I need work with value in WHERE part?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if criteria queries support bitwise operators explicitly, but I don't see it in the documentation.

One option is to use HQL. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177990/how-to-use-bitwise-operators-in-hql), which suggests the HQL parser will pass through the '&'. I haven't actually tried this.

Another option is that you can define a function in SQL to do the bitwise work and then use it in your query. This [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/10/01/UsingSQLFunctionsInNHibernate.aspx) covers using native SQL functions from NH. You can make a function like (haven't tested at all):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BitwiseAnd (@something integer, @andedwith integer) RETURNS bit as
        return select @something & @andedwith
```