# Bitwise AND with NHibernate and Oracle

Tags: linq, oracle, nhibernate, hql, bit-manipulation

I am using Fluent NHibernate 1.0RC (for NHibernate 2.1.4000) together with Linq 2 NHibernate, and I want to execute a query with a bitwise and operation. I first tried using Linq like this, but that did not work:

```
var objects = _session.Linq<MyClass>()
                      .Where(x => (x.someInteger & otherInteger) > 0)
                      .ToList();
```

My conclusion here was that bitwise operations was not supported by Linq 2 Nhibermate. So I tried using HQL instead:

```
var objects =  _session.CreateQuery("select c from MyClass c 
                                     where c.someInteger & :param > 0")
                                .SetParameter("param", otherInteger)
                                .List<MyClass>();
```

This did not work either. It gave me an ora-01036 error: "illegal variable name/number".

So my questions are: Is it even possible to use bitwise operations with NHibernate? Is it supported out of the box with NHibernate 3.0? Is this problematic because I am using an Oracle DB, which will expect bitand() function instead of an & operator?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177990/how-to-use-bitwise-operators-in-hql ?

Comment: I do not think it is, since I already tried the solution given in that thread. The only difference was probably that I am using Oracle, but it seems that it required a completely different solution because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the Oracle dialect and add *BITAND* as a recoginzed HQL function:

```
public class OraclePlusDialect : Oracle10gDialect
{
    public OraclePlusDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("bitand", new StandardSQLFunction("bitand", NHibernateUtil.Int32));
    }    
}
```

Then you should be able to execute your query like this:

```
var objects =  _session.CreateQuery("select c from MyClass c 
                     where bitand(c.someInteger, :param) > 0")
                 .SetParameter("param", otherInteger)
                 .List<MyClass>();
```

Possibly, Oracle has a type conversion problem becuase *BITAND* returns a rarely used data type. If this is the case, modify your HQL query to:

```
select c from MyClass c 
    where bitand(c.someInteger, :param) + 0 > 0
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked straight away without the "+ 0" part